# hibernate get me Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm trying to make a program by using hibernate search and hibernate ORM, actually it is the first time of mine to work with both of these libraries. So please help me.

I added the dependencies as described by the tutorial but it keep getting me this error

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)

the libraries version i am using are:

- hibernate core :5.3.1.Final
- hibernate search :5.10.1.Final
- jdk: 8
- os: debian stretch

I looked everywhere around the web but I cannot find a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a complete stack trace? if not then post full stack trace. Show the code and config how you init. hibernate and sessionfactory.

Comment: Judging from your stacktrace, you are using WildFly or JBoss EAP. Which version are you using? How are you bundling Hibernate ORM/Search into your application server: as libraries, or as separate JBoss modules?

Comment: Looks like you have Hibernate ORM 4 on the classpath as well. Make sure you have the right versions only.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Yes i am using WildFly 9.1 and i'm bundling hibernate orm/search as libraries using maven and this is the complete stack trace for this error plus i cannot find the hibernate orm 4 on my classpath.Thank you for your replies.